# How to build a nested drawer menu with React Native or stack navigation inside Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to build an app using react-native and got stuck in navigation. I want a nested drawer menu inside my app.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to make a nested drawer in react native. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a drawer in react native you can use react-navigation in that there are two components such as stack navigation it is for making the navigation between the screen and for the drawer, there is Drawernavigator by this you can easily make the navigation as well as the drawer in the app in react native.

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  "Here put the screen on which you need drawer."
},{
  contentComponent: SideDrawer,
})
```

after that add the drawer to the stack navigator.

```js
const stack = StackNavigator({
  drawer:{screen: Drawer},
  "And add the screens on which you don't want drawer."
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

It is the way you can make a drawer.